# No se ejecuta todos los comando de mi archivo .bat en CMD

Tags: cmd, .bat

esta es la primera vez que publico aqui.
Estoy intentando hacer un archivo .bat para que me modifique la dirección ip estática de un equipo, pero al ejecutarlo solo se queda en el comando **netsh** y no se ejecutan los demás comandos, les dejo el código para que lo vean:

```
@ECHO OFF
title "CAMBIO DE IP LOCAL"
netsh
interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" static 192.0.3.168 255.255.240.0 192.0.3.1 1
interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" dnsservers 8.8.8.8 index=1
exit
exit
```

[image: se queda en netsh]

pd: ya se esta ejecutando como administrador.

Gracias

Comment: A simple vista, tenes que remover el salto de línea después de `netsh`. Es decir debería ser `netsh interface ....` en la misma línea/renglón. Otra opción es agregar un `^` al final

Answer (score 2):

`netsh` es un programa. Si lo escribes sin parámetros se abre en modo interactivo con su propio contexto por lo que las siguientes líneas no se ejecutarán dentro de `netsh`.

En su lugar, puedes ejecutar cada subcomando pasándolo como parámetro:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" static 192.0.3.168 255.255.240.0 192.0.3.1 1
netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" netsh dnsservers 8.8.8.8 index=1
```

Nota que no tienes que cerrar nada ya que de esta manera, el programa se cierra automáticamente luego de ejecutar cada comando.